# Customize feed on stack exchange android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

I happily enjoys Stack exchange android app. I am really having a good experience browsing through various sections .

However, the questions that appear on first page when I open the app seems to be not from the tags which I like/favorites one. Is there a way to customize which questions to appear ?

Comment: I believe there's a way to set what tags you will see on SE, but I've never used it, and I don't know if it exists for the android app.

Comment: I think it shows top questions from all the stack exchange sites which user has account on ....

Comment: The feed once showed me a question from the Portuguese Stack Overflow. I only realized it was the Portuguese site when the app told me I needed to create an account to flag it. I assume the feed is just showing the hot network questions or similar.

Comment: So should we assume there is no way to achieve this ? Maybe this can be implemented as a new feature as it seems very reasonable to have a control on things which we want to look at very often.

Comment: Yes, the feed is really annoying as-is. Please please make it customizable.